# How can I make a reactive function global?

Tags: shiny, rstudio

In the following code how can I use myData() object in otherfunction() which is another function written to impliment in server function. Rightnow myData() is local ? How can I make it global?

```
library(shiny)
write.csv(data.frame(a = 1:10, b = letters[1:10]), 'test.csv')
runApp(list(ui = fluidPage(
titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
accept=c('text/csv',
'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
'.csv'))
),
mainPanel(
tableOutput('contents')
)
)
)
, 
shinyServer (function(input, output, session){
myData <- reactive({
inFile <- input$file1
if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
data
})
output$contents <- renderTable({
myData()
})

theotherfunction=theotherfunction(input,output,session)

}
)
)
)
```

Comment: how exactly would `theotherfunction` be different from a server function and why would you need it?

Comment: A reactive has indeed a scope, that you may re-define specifying the `env = parent.frame()` clause.  But I wouldn't get there! More simply you could use a `reactiveValue`  instead of a `reactive`. You can define and refer a `reactiveValue` in any part of our code, as it is just a `function` that returns an object for storing reactive values.